# Table Alignment in MSWord

Tags: c#, ms-word

Im generating few tables in word document, one of my table is having more number of columns, so it is going beyond my document page width and few columns in it are not visible, if im trying to set its width then the column names in the table are wrapping up

My goal is :

1. I want the table to autofit in the page irrespective of the no of
   columns.
2. The column names should not wrap up, i.e the column names
   should be displayed in single line.

Comment: 1. Are you using interop? 2. So if you have 100 column with long heading text, do you want the to be all on one line and you want to stretch a page then? 3. Or you want to keep your pagesize the same, and headings should overflow. Can you provide screenshots of what you're trying to achieve if possible

Comment: yes, im using interop...if i have 100 columns with long heading text, i want that heading text of columns to be in sameline in the table, 3)the page size should be  the same..trying for some screen shot..

Comment: What if your headings are not going to fit? Do we have to reduce font-size?

Comment: to be clear, i was not instructed anything about that, so  i want to reduce the fontsize for now..of the table..

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to do what you want, i.e. fit text without wrapping by changing font-size.
 You will have to figure it out manually.
Max you can do is to explicitly specify height for the header row. you can do it like this:

```
           tbl.Rows[1].HeightRule = WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly;
           tbl.Rows[1].Height = 14;
```

Now you can try to change font-size of your text to see if it fits. That's all you can do unfortunately.

**One crazy idea:** you can try to create a formula that will work something like this:
1. get column width after the table was created.
2. count number of characters in a header string.
3. Read specification for the font you're using and figure out how much space each letter takes, and also how much space each [space] character takes.
4. Now you have all available data to build a formula to see what the font-size in points should be for the particular cell. You will have to iterate through all columns to perform this.
5. Select min font size from all calculations and apply to each heading for consistency.
That being said, this is a fragile approach and it's likely going to fail. And I doubt that you can get it to work even closely.

**Advice**: you should call this feature impossible. You don't want to hack word to do things that it's not supposed to do.

Comment: using the above 2 lines of code u provided , im able to restrict the column names from wrapping up and display them in the same line...is there any chance to split the table and display extra columns below it, i mean if there are 10 columns for a table, i want to display 5 columns in one line and another 5 columns below it so that the table fits exactly to the page size...

Comment: @colorsbright, AFAIK you cannot do this. What you should do is to create table with 5 columns. and then just fill 2 rows with your headings.

Comment: ,yes splitting table might be impossible, so there is no otherway to display my table with all columns in my page?also in the code u provided oTable.Rows[1].HeightRule=WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly; wat is that rows[1], will this reflect to all columns in all the tables?

Comment: sorry,by using the above 2 lines u provided, the column names are not being displayed completely..if the column name is 'domestic growth'  then only domestic is being displayed,if i incresed the height form 14 to 24 then 'domestic' is displayed in one line and 'growth' below it..

Comment: @colorsbright, yes, that is exactly what the code is doing. it has nothing to do with font-size or alignment. it just restricts height of the row

Comment: @colorsbright, row 1 will reflect all columns on the first row for the specified table only